# CUDA's cudaMemcpyToSymbol() throws "invalid argument" error

Tags: c, cuda

**The problem**

I'm trying to copy an `int` array into the device's constant memory, but I keep getting the following error:

> [ERROR] 'invalid argument' (11) in 'main.cu' at line '386'

**The code**

There's a lot of code developed, so I'm going to simplify what I have.

I've declared a device `__constant__` variable at the top section of my main.cu file, outside any function.

```
__device__ __constant__ int* dic;
```

I also have a host variable, `flatDic`, that's malloc'ed the following way, inside `main()`:

```
int* flatDic = (int *)malloc(num_codewords*(bSizeY*bSizeX)*sizeof(int));
```

Then I try to copy the contents of `flatDic` into `dic` by doing so, also in `main()`:

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dic, flatDic, num_codewords*(bSizeY*bSizeX)*sizeof(int));
```

This `cudaMemcpyToSymbol()` call it's line 386 of main.cu, and it's where the aforementioned error is thrown.

**What I've tried**

Here's what I've tried so far to solve the problem:

I've tried the all of the following, returning always the same error:

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dic, &flatDic, num_codewords*(bSizeY*bSizeX)*sizeof(int));

cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dic, flatDic, num_codewords*(bSizeY*bSizeX)*sizeof(int));

cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dic, &flatDic, num_codewords*(bSizeY*bSizeX)*sizeof(int), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dic, flatDic, num_codewords*(bSizeY*bSizeX)*sizeof(int), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

I've also tried to `cudaMalloc()` the `dic` variable, before calling `cudaMemcpyToSymbol()`. No errors are thrown in `cudaMalloc()`, but `cudaMemcpyToSymbol()` error persists.

```
cudaMalloc((void **) &dic, num_codewords*(bSizeY*bSizeX)*sizeof(int));
```

I've also search extensively thorough the web, documentation, forums, examples, etc, all to no avail.

Does anyone see anything wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I've also search extensively thorough the web, documentation, forums, examples, etc, all to no avail."

...for basic calls ALWAYS start with the CUDA C Programming guide -- 1. Press `Ctrl + S` and type the call you're looking into your browser/PDF reader. 2. Read anything applicable & look at the guide's code samples.  3. If #2 fails, only then go forum diving.  In this case info was right in the guide, direct form NVIDIA -- just some future advice on how to approach CUDA API call issues.

Comment: I usually start with the reference guide, which is available in HTML format.  [Here's the CUDA 4.1 reference](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/modules.html)  Google for the call name usually turns this up.  After you check the reference, then check the programming guide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cudaMemcpyToSymbol` copies to a constant variable, here you're trying to copy multiple bytes of type `int` (an allocated ARRAY) to a pointer of type `int *`.  These types are not the same, hence the `invalid type`.  To make this work, you will need to copy an ARRAY of `int` (allocated) to the device (static length) ARRAY of `int` (constant), e.g.:

```
__device__ __constant__ int dic[LEN];
```

Example from the [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) (which I suggest you read -- it's quite good!):

```
__constant__ float constData[256];
float data[256];
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(constData, data, sizeof(data));
cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(data, constData, sizeof(data));
```

To my knowledge you could also `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` a pointer to a pointer (unlike your example, where you're copying an array to a pointer), but beware only that *pointer* will be constant, not the memory it's pointing to on your device.  If you were going to go this route, you would need to add a `cudaMalloc`, then `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` the resulting ptr to device memory to your `__constant__` device var.  AGAIN, in this case the array values WILL NOT be constant -- ONLY the pointer to the memory will be.

Your call for this case would be something like:

```
int * d_dic;
cudaMalloc((void **) &d_dic, num_codewords*(bSizeY*bSizeX)*sizeof(int));
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(c_dic_ptr, &d_Dic, sizeof(int *));
```

Also you should be wrapping your CUDA calls during debugging inside error checking logic.  I've borrowed the following logic from [talonmies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681865/talonmies):

```
__inline __host__ void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, 
                 bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code),
          file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
```

To call simply wrap your CUDA call in it like so:

```
gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dic, flatDic, num_codewords*(bSizeY*bSizeX)*sizeof(int)));
```

The programming will exit with an error message if you're having allocation issues or other common errors.

To check your kernel, do something like:

```
MyKernel<<<BLK,THRD>>>(vars...);

//Make sure nothing went wrong.
gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
```

Thanks to [talonmies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681865/talonmies) for the error checking code!

**Note:**
 
Even if you were doing a vanilla `cudaMemcpy`, your code would fail as you haven't `cudaMalloc`ed memory for your array -- int that case, though, the failure would likely be the GPU equivalent of a segfault (likely `Unspecified launch failure`) as the pointer would have some sort of junk value in it and you would be trying to write the memory with the address given by that junk value.

Comment: Please note that the size in cudaMemcpyToSymbol is sizeof(int *) and  not sizeof(int) as it is truely a pointer copy.